# Acceder a propiedades de objetos de modelo en AdonisJs

Tags: adonisjs, adonis-5

buen día, estoy teniendo problemas accediendo a los atributos de un modelo. Ejemplo: de un modelo `Pedido` un atributo sería el `numero_pedido`. Mi problema es que no se como acceder a ese atributo `numero_pedido` a partir de una query de un pedido como esta:

```
const pedido = await Pedido.query().where('id_empresa', 1).orderBy('id', 'desc').limit(1)
```

Y la salida es algo como esto:

```
[
    {
        "id": 30,
        "id_empresa": 1,
        "id_vendedor": 7,
        "numero_pedido": 1,
        "id_cliente": 1,
        "fecha_pedido": "2021-10-14T00:00:00.000-03:00",
        "procesado": 0,
        "estado": 1
    }
]
```

He probado hacer la query algo distinta y agregarle `as unknown as Pedido` al final, y parecería que logra tomar las propiedades de un objeto Pedido, pero si yo devuelvo los datos uno por uno, por ejemplo `return pedido.id` no obtengo nada.

Lo que busco es poder realizar algo como esto:

```
var numero_pedido = pedido.numero_pedido + 1
```

He intentado buscar en la documentación pero no menciona nada sobre esto. Es básicamente poder acceder a los atributos de un objeto de un modelo como el id, el numero_pedido, etc. a través del objeto devuelto por la query. Cualquier ayuda es agradecida y bienvenida!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comento que:

1.- La salida que tu consulta otorga no es un objeto sino un array de objetos, por ende la sintaxis que empleas no va a funcionar y deberías hacerlo de esta forma:

```
let numero_pedido = pedido[0].numero_pedido + 1
```

De tal modo que le indicas que obtenga el numero de pedido del objeto que esta en el índice 0 del array.

2.- Sin embargo podemos ahorrar el declarar el índice si cambiamos de método de `limit` a [`first`](https://docs.adonisjs.com/reference/database/query-builder#first) así:

```
const pedido = await Pedido.query()
                           .where('id_empresa', 1)
                           .orderBy('id', 'desc')
                           .first()
```

Que te daría una salida de este tipo (o `NULL` en una tabla de 0 filas):

```
{
 ...............,
 ...............
}
```

Donde ahora si podrás emplear la sintaxis que previamente tenías:

```
let numero_pedido = pedido.numero_pedido + 1
```

Notas:

- El acceso a los elementos del array de objetos es mas un tema de JS que del framework en si (recomiendo repases el lenguaje base)
- **A menos que uses el método `first` o su variante `firstOrFail` toda consulta `SELECT` te va a retornar un array de objetos**, recomiendo [leas este apartado de la documentación para ampliar](https://docs.adonisjs.com/reference/database/query-builder#first)